# Foundation 5.2 - dropdown submenu direction

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I am trying to have my `Share` dropdown submenu content right aligned, not below `Share`

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" data-options="is_hover:true" >More</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a href="#">Infos</a></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown" ><a href="#">Share</a>
        <ul class="dropdown" >
            <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Third option</a></li>
</ul>
```

with custom css added to the original foundation one:

```
.has-dropdown ul{display:none;}
.has-dropdown:hover ul{display:block;}
```

The problem is that I cannot access `Third option` link, so I would like to have the `This i a link`, `This another`, `Yet another` submenu not below `Share` but just on the right...

As I found in the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html), I tried to add some `data-options="align:right"` like this:

```
<li class="has-dropdown" ><a data-options="align:right" href="#">Share</a>
```

... with no success...  :(

***EDIT1***

With Sai Ram Sudheer answer, I have:

[image]

Not really better..

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing is by aligning text in ul to right

```
.has-dropdown ul{display:none;}
.has-dropdown:hover ul{display:block;text-align:right;}
```

or you can use class right over li elements

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" data-options="is_hover:true" >More</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
    <li><a href="#">Infos</a></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown" ><a href="#">Share</a>
        <ul class="dropdown" >
            <li class="right"><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#">Third option</a></li>
</ul>
```

oops i didn't get the question before.
I tried with data-options="align:left" but unable to get it to the right of main menu.
Check the navigation in this [link](http://dialoguebooth.com/player/home/1/) that i did a while back .I used jquery and some css to get it.